# Why is a html form post to a restlet resource not working?

Tags: html, google-app-engine, forms, post, restlet

Restlet's (2.0M6 on Google App Engine) annotations are actually sensible to the order of a resource's methods. 
When posting html form data, make sure that the @Post("html") method stays above the @Post("xml") method in the receiving resource.
At least Firefox puts both content types into the request's Accept header, so the first matching method will be processed.

**The question is**, if there is any other way to achieve control over method precedence?

For example I would like the client to accept text/html only.

Comment: Is "html" the right representation for "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"?

Comment: @PartlyCloudy: It's about what kind of representation is sent back to the client, after the app has received "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" post data.
Since forms are usually in html, so should the response be (opposed to for example ajax post requests, that usually result in xml).

Comment: Not sure I understand "I would like the client to accept text/html only." If you're implementing a server, not a client, then you can't control what the client sends in the `Accept` header. You can only control how your server interprets the request, and how it responds.

Can you clarify your question a little? Are you asking about a situation wherein a client specifies multiple types in the `Accept` header, and you want to prefer one type over another, regardless of how they're specified in the `Accept` header?

Comment: @Avi: I guess my question was, if there is some kind of client-side html form attribute or JavaScript to modify the accept header.
I know how to work with XmlHttpRequest, but that seems a bit to heavy for my purposes (being just rendering simple html forms if client requests them and sending back html, not xml, only in that specific case).
Your comment thus was kind of an answer: It is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment that you're asking whether there is some kind of client-side html form attribute or JavaScript to modify the accept header, the answer would be, AFAIK: no. Not for links clicked or forms submitted by the user. As you mentioned in your comment, you might be able to use JS to intercept link clicks and form posts, and use XHR instead, but that'd probably be tricky, if possible.

BTW, XmlHttpRequest doesn't really have anything to do with XML. It can handle any sort of content, for both requests and responses. It's very common to return a snippet of HTML to a XHR request and use DOM injection to dynamically update the page.